# Prevent Search Engines from Indexing WordPress Blog

Tags: wordpress, indexing, search-engine, robots.txt

that might seems like an easy question but I'm struggling on this problem since monday.
There's a wordpress website that I need to be hidden when searching for the keywords contained in it, but I can't work it out.

I already tryied to:

- Add a robots.txt, on the main root, on the httdocs folder, and on the folder containing the website.
- Use the in-built function of wordpress.
- Protect the website with a password

None of them seems to be working, so I deleted the website (that was a staging website btw) but it keeps being indexed on search engines.

What shall I do?

Comment: Your question is off-topic as it's not programming related but about SEO. Please ask here instead: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Robots.txt is the solution. However you need to realize it can take weeks for google remove the site from index.

For other options see "Make removal permanent" part - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en